# VBA exits before end

Tags: excel, vba

***EDIT*** 
I got it to run thru about 1,000 part numbers, but now it stops and excel freezes. Is it possibly too much for excel to handle? Would it be better to add a filter and have user perform this task based off criteria xyz?

I'm using the following code to create a mass form replacement. It's intended to run through a list of 5000+ part numbers, paste the part number into a designated range on another worksheet where it creates the form and saves it as a pdf in a specified folder. It works up until row 105 and then stops. It does what it's supposed to, other than continue down the sheet. I have the same code (modified slightly) being used on another sheet and it runs perfect. I'm not sure why its stopping after a certain number of rows

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")
Dim x As Worksheet
Dim y As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To FinalRow
    Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Part Number Database")
    Set y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BOM")
    x.Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=y.Range("E3:J3")

strFile = Range("E3") & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\AGoodwin\Desktop\BOM\" & strFile & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next i

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile

End Sub
```

Comment: At some point are you using a line such as `on error goto exitHandler`? As you don't have it in the code provided and I'd assume you'd be getting a useful error rather than it simply stopping if you weren't.

Comment: Didn't realize I had left that part of code in there when I copied it over to here. It was removed in the VBA.

Comment: I don't think the 'exithandler' would cause the loop to end early. I'd explicitly declare your `FinalRow` variable. At the moment it will take the Row number from whatever the active sheet is. It would be better to declare it with the intended sheet instead so `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row` (And also would be best to do similar for the `Rows.Count`)

Comment: Also, I'd move your `set x = ` and `set y = ` out of your loop as they don't vary inside the loop so it is pointless to set them 5000+ times or whatever it is

Comment: Try adding **`On Error Goto 0`** at the start of your function and see if it throws an error. That should help to identify the issue

Comment: @Tom it's an unknown factor so we need to consider unless proven otherwise. As tom says strictly defining the workbook/worksheet for the assignment of finalrow would help. If you set a breakpoint at the start of the loop you can check what final row is being set as.

Comment: I'd agree with @Tom - be explicit about which sheet you intend the code to look at.  It might be worth putting `Debug.Assert i<>105` after your `For i = 3 To FinalRow` line to pause the code when it reaches row 105.  You can then step through the code to see what's different about that row.  (`Debug.Assert False` will pause code - `i<>105` will return FALSE when it reaches 105).

Comment: Unrelated to the problem - I'd also consider renaming the `x` and `y` variables.  It's not easy to see what they refer to, whereas names such as `wrkSht_Target`, `wrkSht_Source` or `wrkSht_PND` and `wrkSht_BOM` are a bit more obvious.

Comment: Just a quick guess - does row 105 contain a merged cell?

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I moved the set x & y out of the loop and declared my Finalrow. It continued past row 105, but then I ran into the part numbers that had an " * " at the end that prevented the save file. Added a replace line and everything seems to running as it should. Thank you for your help :)